# Removing character from string in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, one column of which is filled with entries like this:

```
2017-03-01T09:30:00.436
2017-03-01T09:30:00.444
...
```

Is there a way to convert the entire column into datetime format?

So far I have tried using

```
str.replace('T',' ') over iterrows()
```

as well as slicing methods but neither seems to work. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sure  thing @jezrael! Thanks for your help again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `regex=True` for [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) substrings:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].replace('T', ' ', regex=True)
```

But maybe need only [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['2017-03-01T09:30:00.436','2017-03-01T09:30:00.444']})

df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'])
print (df['col'])
0   2017-03-01 09:30:00.436
1   2017-03-01 09:30:00.444
Name: col, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 0):

`to_datetime()` should work in converting it to datetime format